# Why does ZSH return “Command not found” error for sudo motion update?

Tags: terminal, installation, zsh, sudo, rubymotion

I'm trying to install RubyMotion.  I type

```
     sudo motion update
```

into my terminal and get back

```
     sudo: motion: command not found
```

What could be causing this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the output of `whence -v motion`. What is the output of this command after you do a `sudo -s` (starts a shell as root) or `sudo -i` (the same but runs a login shell as root).

Comment: after whence -v motion I get back motion not found.

Comment: after sudo -s or sudo -i the output is whence: command not found.

Comment: What's the output of `which motion` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install it using the installer package first, did you already do that?